# The concept of continuity in a topological group

Tags: group-theory, general-topology

I am now learning the [Lie group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) theory. People talk about the fundamental group of a topological group. The problem is, how is the continuity defined in a [topological group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group)? In other words, in which sense we say two elements are close to each other?

I think we need a metric to define continuity. That is, we first need to define the distance between two arbitrary group elements. But I never see people speaking about the distance between two elements in the $SO(3)$ group.

Comment: You don't need a metric to define continuity. A simple google search would have shown you that continuity can be defined [for functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_topological_spaces) on arbitrary topological spaces. However, this question has nothing to do with physics, so I'm voting to migrate to [math.se]

Comment: I think it is related to physics. Every physicist has to learn topology today.

Comment: @kaiser Whether every physicist has to learn topology or not, that does not make your *question* related to physics just because topology is used in physics. You have not mentioned anything from physics in your question. I'm voting to migrate as well.

Comment: So you mean, a metric is not needed, what is needed is a topology, namely, a declaration of open sets.

Comment: "Every physicist has to learn topology today". So incorrect.

Comment: @MarkMitchison you may not have to learn it, but you will use it anyways...and quite often ;-)

Comment: @yuggib Quite the opposite. I do learn topology out of interest, but it has very little or no useful application to my work.

Comment: @MarkMitchison So the only mathematical constructs you use are sets (and maybe categories)? I don't see e.g. how you could define the rational numbers as a dense subset of the reals without topology...Therefore I believe that everyone uses (many times implicitly) a lot of topological concepts, even in physics.

Comment: @yuggib Ah, so you were making a funny joke. OK man, sorry for not laughing at first :) Obviously all physicists use topology in that totally trivial sense. So also does my retired (non-physicist) mother whenever she walks down the street without being impeded by Zeno's paradox. I don't think that is really what the OP meant. Rather, they seem to be expressing the belief that "every physicist" is a string theorist/high energy theorist or a condensed matter theorist, who do indeed regularly use topologically non-trivial concepts (geddit?). But there's an awful lot more physics beyond that.

Comment: @MarkMitchison Yes I was making a joke, and there is no need to be picky. Also, you seem to have a very strange concept of triviality: looking at your [poster](https://workspace.imperial.ac.uk/controlledquantumdynamics/Public/Posters/Mark%20Mitchison%20-Windsor2013%20(2).pdf) here, in the third line you use Lindblad equation, that has been formulated by Lindblad using $C^*$-algebras of operators, and I can assure you it is quite important to establish which type of topology (in particular the notion of continuity) you use for the automorphism that defines the Lindblad map and guarantees it has

Comment: @MarkMitchison ...such a form. In addition, then you make the "product ansatz", using a direct product of operators. Again to define this notion you need the possibility of completing cartesian products of Hilbert spaces and the suitable (trivial?) topology that it results from it. But, evidently, is all trivial, or unknown, to you; probably there is an awful lot of mathematics inside the physics you consider...

Comment: @yuggib Clearly, all is unknown to me, rather than trivial. By the way, my comment was meant to genuinely light-hearted; this intent was obviously lost in translation over the internet so I apologise if you felt I was being vindictive in any way. I find all of the points you mentioned very interesting, but you do not need to understand any of it to use (or indeed, to understand) the techniques in question.

Comment: I can give a perfectly good derivation of a Lindblad equation that does not invoke $C^*$-algebras, but rather requires only some linear algebra and calculus. Likewise a perfectly good physical justification for product states  invokes just some probability theory and the Born rule. So although this topological viewpoint is great, I don't think it is fair to claim that it somehow "underlies" everything. It is just one mathematical way of expressing physics. But I see that you have spent at least some of your career as a mathematician and so this is not a discussion likely to end in agreement :)

Comment: @MarkMitchison Ok, got it; no offence taken, and sorry,I just read it the wrong way ;-) Anyways I agree that we have simply two different "philosophical" approaches, and I do not think at all that one is better than the other. And by the way, I enjoyed looking at your work, it is indeed interesting ;-)

Comment: @yuggib No worries, thanks for the compliment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you an answer just for completeness, because Danu pretty much covered it with his comment.

Given two topological spaces $(X,\mathscr{T})$ and $(Y,\mathscr{S})$, we say that a function $f:X\to Y$ is **continuous** if the pre-image $f^{-1}[A]\in \mathscr{T}$ for any $A\in\mathscr{S}$ ($\mathscr{T},\mathscr{S}$ are the respective collections of open sets).

Also, to define the notion of a limit you just need a topological space. Let $(X,\mathscr{T})$ be a topological space; we call a set $N$ a **neighborhood** of $x$ if there exists an open set $A\in\mathscr{T}$ with $x\in A\subset N$. Then we say that a sequence (or also a net) $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ **converges** to $x\in X$ if for any neighborhood $N$ of $x$, there is a $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n\in N$ for any $n\geq m$.

If the topology is $T_2$ or Hausdorff, i.e. separates points, limits can be shown to be unique.

Observe that given a metric/norm/inner product you have automatically a topology "inherited" from these structures, and thus an associated notion of continuity and convergence; nevertheless it is not necessary to define them in order to have these notions.

Comment: Although the intent is good, of course, I can't help but feel that answering questions like this (which quite obviously belong on [math.se] instead of here) is not a good idea because it subtly encourages people to ask types of questions that (here, I am of course speaking for myself) aren't wanted here.

Comment: @Danu Ok, I see your point...